# Click on link does not fire or doesn't trigger navigation

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to visit a website and click on a link. Unfortunately, I cannot get the click on the link to work. Here is a minimal non-working example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({ width: 1600, height: 900 });

  await page.goto('https://dl.acm.org/doi/proceedings/10.1145/3337932');

  let arrMainLinks = await page.$$('.issue-item__title');
  for(let i = 0; i < arrMainLinks.length; ++i)
  {
    await page.waitForSelector('.issue-item__title a', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    const x = arrMainLinks[i];
    await x.hover();
    await x.click();
    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    // do things

    await page.goBack();
    await page.waitForSelector('body', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    arrMainLinks = await page.$$('.issue-item__title a')
  }
})();
```

Things I've tried:

- The `Promise.all` trick a quick google search suggests
- `page.eval(x => x.click(), x)`
- `waitFor(20000)` before clicking

How can I get this to work and just click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the selector:

```
  let arrMainLinks = await page.$$('.issue-item__title a');
```

The way it is in the question emit a click on the `h2` element, changing it to the `a` element works.